# Typescript check exported interface

Tags: typescript

How can I typecheck the exported symbols for a module?

For instance, consider a plugin-based system where the plugins must implement and export a predefined API (e.g. a function prototype or interface)

```js
type MyPluginCallback = (foo: string) => number;
```

When implementing a plugin I would like to have a build error if the plugin does not implement the given API.

```js
/* OK */
module.exports = function myPlugin(foo: string): number {
  /* ... */
}

/* Error, wrong prototype */
module.exports = function myPlugin(bar: number): number {
  /* ... */
}
```

Is it possible in Typescript? If so, how?

Comment: Is that plugin come from a node module you have? If so, checking you may share your typescript configuration to see the value of [`skipLibCheck`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52311779/usage-of-the-typescript-compiler-argument-skiplibcheck) property.

Comment: It is when I implement the plugin I would like to see build failures, for instance if the API is changed in the consumer project in a later version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) `as MyPluginCallback` for that purpose. `as MyPluginCallback` performs a type compatibility check, before it assigns the type `MyPluginCallback` to the function expression at hand.

```
type MyPluginCallback = (foo: string) => number

module.exports = function myPlugin_OK(bar: string): number {
  return 42
} as MyPluginCallback // ✅

module.exports = function myPlugin_Error(bar: number): number {
  return 42
} as MyPluginCallback //
```

Alternatively assign the function to a variable with `MyPluginCallback` type, and export it in a second step.

```
const myPlugin_OK: MyPluginCallback = (bar: string): number => 42 // ✅
const myPlugin_Error: MyPluginCallback = (bar: number): number => 42 // 

module.exports = myPlugin_OK
module.exports = myPlugin_Error
```