# Angular typescript typecheck issues when importing tensorflow in web worker

Tags: angular, typescript, tensorflow, web-worker, tsconfig

I am trying to use tensorflow/tfjs (TF) in a web-worker in an angular project.

Creating a web-worker using the `ng generate worker` command works just fine.

Importing TF in a component is fine too.

However importing TF in the worker i.e. :

```
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs'
```

Generates a bunch of missing definition errors when building through the `ng build` command. Missing types are typically DOM-related types such as `error TS2304: Cannot find name ImageData | HTMLImageElement | HTMLCanvasElement | HTMLVideoElement`.
Those types are used in some definitions in TF and, as I understand, those types are not accessible with web-workers because [DOM manipulation cannot be done from workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers).
I am perfectly fine with that, my use of TF doesn't rely on those types. But I still need to find a way to build my worker.

I therefore tried to tinker with the `tsconfig.worker.json` file. My first attempt was to mimic the other tsconfig* files by adding "dom" in the `compilerOptions.lib` array :

```
["es2018", "webworker"]
```

replaced by

```
["es2018", "webworker", "dom"]
```

This results in conflicting types definitions

```
error TS6200: Definitions of the following identifiers conflict with those in another file
```

the **webworker** and **dom** libs have different definitions for the same types, but I can of course not remove the webworker lib reference.

My 2nd attempt was to add the `skipTypeCheck` compiler option in the `tsconfig.worker.json` file :
**That works just fine**, I got TF running in my web worker and outputting results.

BUT...

Skipping type checking feels like ripping of the whole idea of using typescript. So my question is :

**Is there a cleaner way to use TF in a webworker in angular while preserving type checking ?**

Thanks for your anwsers. Please let me know if I should provide more configuration details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the official TensorFlow tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/js/tutorials/setup

> When using TypeScript you may need to set skipLibCheck: true in your tsconfig.json file if your project makes use of strict null checking or you will run into errors during compilation.

This is better than `skipTypeCheck` as types in your code are still checked. This way the code compiles but you still get an error in console: `Error when getting WebGL context:  Error: Cannot create a canvas in this context`.

But that is not a problem so far.

Comment: I actually don't use WebGL contexts, so your solution works just fine. Thanks