# Build failed because of no export of ParsedQs from express-serve-static-core

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, typescript-typings

I was faced with an error of `[@types/express]-Type 'P' is not assignable to type 'ParamsArray'`, the error was resolved by installing these specific packages `"@types/express": "^4.17.8", "@types/express-serve-static-core": "^4.17.13"` which throw a new error below. I have tried to downgrade `"@types/express-serve-static-core"` to `"^4.17.5"` and install `qs`, but none of these work.

Any suggestions on how to fix this error?

`node_modules/@types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts:30:10 - error TS2305: Module '"../qs"' has no exported member 'ParsedQs'.`

`30 import { ParsedQs } from "qs";`

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be a known problem with that package ([see this issue](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/47339#issuecomment-689695381)).  I don't think an update for that has been released yet, but in the meantime you can use `--skipLibCheck` to prevent tsc from looking into packages that deeply and finding that error.  [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56268670/5676389) explains what that flag does nicely.

Comment: Thank you, what I did is that I deleted all the part containing "qs" and it's types, and run `yarn`

Answer (score 1):

Here I found the solution by following the steps below:

1. npm remove @types/express && npm add @types/express@latest
2. delete the @types/express-serve-static-core
3. npm update @types/express-serve-static-core --depth 1
4. npm remove @types/express && npm i @types/express-serve-static-core@latest

Solved Problem

Thanks.

Comment: For me, it was enough to do `yarn remove @types/express && yarn add --dev @types/express-serve-static-core@latest @types/express`.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the following thing

```
npm install typescript@4.1.6

npm install -D @types/express-serve-static-core@4.17.30
```