# ERROR TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context

Tags: node.js, angular, nebular

TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

when i try to run the project using i am getting these  error i have tried
running npm install and also tried with cleaning  the cache first
using npm clean command  then again installing using npm install still i am getting these errors

please help and thanks in advance

```
ERROR in node_modules/@rosen-group/ngx-onboarding/lib/models/onboarding-item-container.model.d.ts(14,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/@rosen-group/ngx-onboarding/lib/models/onboarding-item-container.model.d.ts(18,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/@rosen-group/ngx-onboarding/lib/models/onboarding-item-container.model.d.ts(22,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/@rosen-group/ngx-onboarding/lib/models/onboarding-item-container.model.d.ts(26,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/@rosen-group/ngx-onboarding/lib/models/onboarding-item-container.model.d.ts(30,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/@rosen-group/ngx-onboarding/lib/onboarding-button.component.d.ts(15,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in 
an ambient context.
node_modules/@rosen-group/ngx-onboarding/lib/onboarding-button.component.d.ts(19,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in 
an ambient context.
node_modules/@rosen-group/ngx-onboarding/lib/services/build-in-translator.service.d.ts(18,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/@rosen-group/ngx-onboarding/lib/services/onboarding.service.d.ts(42,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in 
an ambient context.
node_modules/@rosen-group/ngx-onboarding/lib/services/translator-base.service.d.ts(16,18): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/@rosen-group/ngx-onboarding/lib/services/window-ref.service.d.ts(5,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/ng2-pdf-viewer/src/app/pdf-viewer/pdf-viewer.component.d.ts(5,10): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/RKC/Documents/lmsclient-master/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/pdf"' has no exported member 'PDFDocumentProxy'.
node_modules/ng2-pdf-viewer/src/app/pdf-viewer/pdf-viewer.component.d.ts(5,28): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/RKC/Documents/lmsclient-master/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/pdf"' has no exported member 'PDFSource'.
node_modules/ng2-pdf-viewer/src/app/pdf-viewer/pdf-viewer.component.d.ts(5,39): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/RKC/Documents/lmsclient-master/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/pdf"' has no exported member 'PDFProgressData'.
node_modules/ng2-pdf-viewer/src/app/pdf-viewer/pdf-viewer.module.d.ts(1,10): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/RKC/Documents/lmsclient-master/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/pdf"' has no exported member 'PDFJSStatic'.
node_modules/ng2-pdf-viewer/src/app/pdf-viewer/pdf-viewer.module.d.ts(5,10): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/RKC/Documents/lmsclient-master/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/pdf"' has no exported member 'PDFJSStatic'.
node_modules/ng2-pdf-viewer/src/app/pdf-viewer/pdf-viewer.module.d.ts(5,23): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/RKC/Documents/lmsclient-master/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/pdf"' has no exported member 'PDFDocumentProxy'.
node_modules/ng2-pdf-viewer/src/app/pdf-viewer/pdf-viewer.module.d.ts(5,41): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/RKC/Documents/lmsclient-master/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/pdf"' has no exported member 'PDFViewerParams'.
node_modules/ng2-pdf-viewer/src/app/pdf-viewer/pdf-viewer.module.d.ts(5,58): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/RKC/Documents/lmsclient-master/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/pdf"' has no exported member 'PDFPageProxy'.
node_modules/ng2-pdf-viewer/src/app/pdf-viewer/pdf-viewer.module.d.ts(5,72): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/RKC/Documents/lmsclient-master/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/pdf"' has no exported member 'PDFSource'.
node_modules/ng2-pdf-viewer/src/app/pdf-viewer/pdf-viewer.module.d.ts(5,83): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/RKC/Documents/lmsclient-master/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/pdf"' has no exported member 'PDFProgressData'.
node_modules/ng2-pdf-viewer/src/app/pdf-viewer/pdf-viewer.module.d.ts(5,100): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/RKC/Documents/lmsclient-master/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/pdf"' has no exported member 'PDFPromise'.
node_modules/ng2-smart-table/lib/components/tbody/tbody.component.d.ts(30,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/ngx-editor/app/ngx-editor/ngx-editor-toolbar/ngx-editor-toolbar.component.d.ts(3,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ngx-bootstrap'.
node_modules/ngx-quicklink/src/link.directive.d.ts(13,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.        
node_modules/ngx-quicklink/src/link.directive.d.ts(14,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.        
node_modules/ngx-show-hide-password/lib/show-hide-status.directive.d.ts(16,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/display/annotation_storage.d.ts(30,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/display/api.d.ts(595,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/display/api.d.ts(599,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/display/api.d.ts(603,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/display/api.d.ts(798,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/display/api.d.ts(802,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/display/api.d.ts(948,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/pdfjs-dist/types/display/api.d.ts(1155,9): error TS186: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.       86: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/quill-delta/dist/Delta.d.ts(1,8): error TS1192: Modu86: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.le '"C:/Users/RKC/Documents/lmsclient-master/node_modules/fast-di86: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.ff/diff"' has no default export.                                 086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
src/app/pages/users/teacherDetails/teacherDetails.component.ts(23086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ngx-bootstrap'.          le '"C:/Users/RKC/Documents/lmsclient-master/node_modules/fast-diff/
src/app/pages/users/user/user.component.ts(23,26): error TS2307: 
Cannot find module 'ngx-bootstrap'
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "learningmgmtsystem",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "LICENCE",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin.git"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin-bundle-support/issues"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "conventional-changelog": "conventional-changelog",
    "start": "node --max_old_space_size=8192 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve --host=0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:prod": "npm run  build -- --prod --aot ",
    "test": "ng test",
    "test:coverage": "rimraf coverage && npm run test -- --code-coverage",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "lint:fix": "ng lint ngx-admin-demo --fix",
    "lint:styles": "stylelint ./src/**/*.scss",
    "lint:ci": "npm run lint && npm run lint:styles",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "docs": "compodoc -p src/tsconfig.app.json -d docs",
    "docs:serve": "compodoc -p src/tsconfig.app.json -d docs -s",
    "prepush": "npm run lint:ci",
    "release:changelog": "npm run conventional-changelog -- -p angular -i CHANGELOG.md -s"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.7",
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "^8.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.2",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.2.2",
    "@angular/material": "^8.1.3",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.2",
    "@angular/router": "^8.2.2",
    "@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet": "3.0.1",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.5.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.11.2",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.25",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.11.2",
    "@fullcalendar/angular": "^4.4.2",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^4.4.2",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^4.4.2",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^4.4.2",
    "@fullcalendar/list": "^4.4.2",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^4.4.2",
    "@kolkov/angular-editor": "^1.1.4",
    "@nebular/auth": "^4.2.2",
    "@nebular/eva-icons": "^4.2.2",
    "@nebular/security": "^4.2.2",
    "@nebular/theme": "^4.2.2",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.1.0",
    "@rosen-group/ngx-onboarding": "^1.3.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^10.0.0",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-charts": "^18.3.35",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-richtexteditor": "^17.2.41",
    "@types/quill": "^2.0.2",
    "@types/socket.io-client": "^1.4.32",
    "@types/web-animations-js": "^2.2.8",
    "@vimeo/player": "^2.12.2",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.27.18",
    "angular-star-rating": "^4.0.0-beta.3",
    "angular-tree-component": "7.2.0",
    "angular2-chartjs": "0.4.1",
    "angular2-toaster": "^7.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.3.1",
    "chart.js": "2.7.1",
    "ckeditor": "4.7.3",
    "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "2.5.1",
    "css-star-rating": "^1.2.4",
    "date-fns": "^1.30.1",
    "echarts": "^4.0.2",
    "error-stack-parser": "^2.0.3",
    "eva-icons": "^1.1.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-rc.7",
    "i": "^0.3.6",
    "igniteui-angular": "^8.1.3",
    "increase-memory-limit": "^1.0.7",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "ionicons": "2.0.1",
    "leaflet": "1.2.0",
    "marked": "^0.7.0",
    "mat-video": "^2.8.1",
    "moment-es6": "^1.0.0",
    "nebular-icons": "1.1.0",
    "ng-animate": "^0.3.4",
    "ng-zorro-antd": "^11.2.0",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.3.3",
    "ng2-ckeditor": "^1.2.4",
    "ng2-completer": "2.0.8",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^5.3.3",
    "ng2-pdfjs-viewer": "^5.0.1",
    "ng2-search-filter": "^0.5.1",
    "ng2-smart-table": "^1.5.0",
    "ngp-sort-pipe": "0.0.4",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.6.2",
    "ngx-echarts": "^4.0.1",
    "ngx-editor": "^4.1.0",
    "ngx-embed-video": "^1.0.4",
    "ngx-extended-pdf-viewer": "^1.6.2",
    "ngx-material-timepicker": "^4.0.2",
    "ngx-pagination": "^4.1.0",
    "ngx-quicklink": "^0.2.0",
    "ngx-show-hide-password": "^2.1.0",
    "ngx-youtube-player": "^7.1.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "normalize.css": "6.0.0",
    "npm": "^6.10.3",
    "pace-js": "1.0.2",
    "primeicons": "^2.0.0",
    "primeng": "^8.0.2",
    "quill": "^1.3.6",
    "roboto-fontface": "0.8.0",
    "rxjs": "6.5.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.3.0",
    "socicon": "3.0.5",
    "stacktrace-js": "^2.0.0",
    "tinymce": "4.5.7",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "typeface-exo": "0.0.22",
    "web-animations-js": "github:angular/web-animations-js#release_pr208",
    "xlsx": "^0.15.4",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.800.2",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "8.0.0",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "1.0.1",
    "@types/d3-color": "1.0.5",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.37.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.54",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.3",
    "@types/leaflet": "1.2.3",
    "@types/node": "6.0.90",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.1",
    "conventional-changelog-cli": "1.3.4",
    "husky": "0.13.3",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.4",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.1.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "karma": "1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "npm-run-all": "4.0.2",
    "protractor": "5.1.2",
    "rimraf": "2.6.1",
    "stylelint": "7.13.0",
    "ts-node": "3.2.2",
    "tslint": "^5.7.0",
    "tslint-language-service": "^0.9.9",
    "typescript": "3.4.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but only posting an error messages is not sufficient here. What are you trying to tell?

Comment: when i run using ng serve i am getting these error

Comment: Did you run `npm install`? The error message is telling me, that `ngx-bootstrap` is missing.

Comment: @Lynx242  yes i had run npm install

Comment: Please, provide your package.json

Comment: @Lynx242 i have added the package.json file

Comment: That's strange. `ngx-bootstrap` is definitely present. I'd recommend to remove the `node_modules`-folder and run `npm install` again. Often this action fixes such inexplicable problems.

Comment: @Lynx242 i have tried deleting the node module folder and then running npm install the error still remains the same

Answer (score 2):

You can skip lib-checking (this is not necessarily a good idea, but it'll most likely solve your immediate problem):

```
"compilerOptions": {
   "skipLibCheck": true,
},
```

(this is done in the `tsconfig.json`-file)

More information about this functionality can be found in this Stackoverflow question: [Usage of the TypeScript compiler argument 'skipLibCheck'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52311779/usage-of-the-typescript-compiler-argument-skiplibcheck)