# NextJS TypeScript issue: randomUUID?(): string - error TS2386: Overload signatures must all be optional or required

Tags: typescript, next.js

I have a mono-rep structure with `Lerna` for 2 NextJS projects and 1 shared project.

Recently I tried to enable **typescript**. The NextJS projects seem working fine (following their docs) but the other throws an issue while compiling.

Package versions:

```
"next": "^12.0.1",
"typescript": "^4.6.2"
```

TypeScript config (`tsconfig.json`):

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "strict": false,
        "target": "es6",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": false,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "allowJs": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "incremental": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "jsx": "preserve"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "dist",
        "jest.*.js",
    ]
}
```

The error:

```
../../node_modules/next/types/index.d.ts:203:5
error TS2386: Overload signatures must all be optional or required.

203:5     randomUUID?(): string
```

Comment: You can exclude `node_modules` or use [`skipLibCheck`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#skipLibCheck).

Comment: @jsejcksn For sure I can but it's more like a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52311779/usage-of-the-typescript-compiler-argument-skiplibcheck). Actually there is same [issue](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/31296) with another library that's preventing compilation atm.
Anyway I'm convinced to use `skipLibCheck`.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like this will be fixed in the next.js release 12.1.1 based on [this PR](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/34976).

For now, you can either 1) roll back typescript to 4.5.5, 2) upgrade to the 12.1.1-canary builds of next.js, or 3) turn on [skipLibCheck](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#skipLibCheck) as was mentioned by [jsejcksn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438273/jsejcksn) and [salar-hafezi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8012972/salar-hafezi).